# Staging SQLite Database Files Reliably

Tags: php, sqlite, atomic, corruption

I have two SQLite database files:

- `data.db` (**Production**)
- `data.db.tmp` (**Staging**)

Both databases are in [WAL journaling mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html). Additionally, the staging database in in exclusive locking mode (using [`PRAGMA locking_mode`](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_locking_mode)) with a single reader / writer, while the production database is in shared / normal locking mode and has several readers and no writers.

At any given point in time, the file structure might look like this:

- `data.db`
- `data.db-shm`
- `data.db-wal`
- `data.db.tmp`
- `data.db.tmp-wal`

Ocasionally, I will want to replace the production database with the staging database - preferably, without disrupting existing [production] readers and, more crucially, without corrupting the database.

My initial (naive) idea was a simple `mv data.db-tmp data.db` but, because there are several related files, a single rename will not guarantee atomicity nor consistency. I then thought of doing a braced `mv`:

```
mv data.db{.tmp,.tmp-wal} data{.db,.db-wal}
```

I don't know if the above is a atomic operation, but it wouldn't work as well given the transient nature of the `*-shm` and `*-wal` files: if `data.db.tmp-wal` doesn't exists the move would fail (I think!) and there is no atomic operation for the possibly existing `data.db-shm` counterpart.

According to `info coreutils 'mv invocation'`:

> Prior to version '4.0' of the fileutils, 'mv' could move only regular
>   files between file systems.  For example, now 'mv' can move an entire
>   directory hierarchy including special device files from one partition
>   to another.  It first uses some of the same code that's used by 'cp -a'
>   to copy the requested directories and files, then (assuming the copy
>   succeeded) it removes the originals.  If the copy fails, then the part
>   that was copied to the destination partition is removed.

Renaming whole folders is also not atomic.

What can I do to make this staging process reliable?

---

*Some additional remarks:*

- my client API is PHP/PDO, so I have no access to the [SQLite online backup C interface](http://www.sqlite.org/backup.html)
- the databases are several GBs in size, so some in-memory solutions might not be viable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command expands to:

```
mv data.db.tmp data.db.tmp-wal data.db data.db-wal
```

Anyway, multiple file system operations are not atomic.

---

To get rid of both `-wal` and `-shm` files, change the journal mode to DELETE; you can change it back later.
Once you have a single database file, you can execute an atomic rename to replace it.

Please note that WAL mode optimizes for writing; it would be a better idea to leave the (read-only) production database in rollback journal mode.

Comment: This had occurred to me, but I wasn't sure it would be that straightforward. Would changing the journal mode to DELETE on the staging database be enough for the production connection to detect that it no longer needs `-wal` and `-shm` files?

Comment: My concern is that if I need to change the journal mode of the **production** database to DELETE as well, a reader might connect to it and as a consequence change the journal mode back to WAL again (before the mv takes place). One way to solve this, would be by setting the locking mode to exclusive on both databases, but that will disrupt future readers and - I'm not sure - might fail if there are any active readers with shared locks at that specific time.

Comment: Active readers will continue to read from the old file; they will see the new file only when it is reopened, i.e., with a new database connection.